# Close unclosed tags in HTML

Tags: java, html, htmlcleaner

I need to get the inner HTML as output for an input complete HTML. However, the getInnerHtml function returns an incomplete HTML that cannot be rendered. A few tags are not closed properly, resulting in this issue.

**Usage:**

```
String possibleUrlData="<input html value>";
TagNode cleanResultNode = cleanString(possibleUrlData);
String result = cleaner.getInnerHtml(cleanResultNode);
```

**Example input tag:**

```
 <script defer="" src="/_next/static/chunks/6848-2e85e2aba8bb65b9.js"></script>
```

**Output:**

```
<script defer="" src="/_next/static/chunks/6848-2e85e2aba8bb65b9.js" />
```

When I close the output tag properly, the HTML becomes renderable.

Please suggest how to deal with this. I do not have much experience with HTMLs, so any advice regarding closing/removing the tags will be helpful.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with `java`. Did you mean `javascript`? Those 2 things are unrelated.

Comment: The resultant HTML is generated via java backend, not javascript.